# Spring mvc hibernate jsp issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I have a problem with a page when I try to delete a user I recive this error An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/Users.jsp at line 92
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/Users.jsp at line 92

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Users")
public String goUsers(Model model)
{

    model.addAttribute("AllUsers", UserS.getAllUsers());
    return "Users";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/Users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String goUsers(@RequestParam("id") int id) 
{
    UserS.deleteUser(id);
    return "Users"; 
}
```

Jsp File

```
</div>
<form:form method="POST" action="Users">
User ID
<form:input path="id"/>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="Supprimer" value="Supprimer">
</form:form>
```

Comment: what is at line 92 ?

Comment: <form:input path="id"/>

Comment: try to add this line model.addAttribute("AllUsers", UserS.getAllUsers()); after  UserS.deleteUser(id);

Comment: I added it but  stil the same probelm

Comment: how do you use  model.addAttribute("AllUsers", UserS.getAllUsers()); in your jsp ?

Comment: <c:forEach items="${AllUsers}" var="user">
 <td>${user.idUser}</td>
 <td>${user.login}</td>
 <td>${user.nom}</td>
 <td>${user.prenom}</td>
 <td>${user.email}</td>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>

Answer (score 0):

use  `/Users` in your form and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

there is no id in model. so you have to add id in your model like :

```
model.addAttribute("AllUsers", UserS.getAllUsers());
model.addAttribute("id", 3);
```

and it will work.